# SQL query to SELECT multiple columns from multiple tables for display

Tags: php, sql, inner-join

I have a `products` table  and an `inventory_order_product` table. I need to select `product_id`, `product_name`, `product_unit` and  `product_status` from `products` table and and also `quantity` from `inventory_order_product` table. I also need to output it in this format - `Product Name (Quantity ProductUnit)` example `LG LED TV (20 Cartons)`

I tried this and it didn't display anything

```php
function fill_product_list($connect)
{
    $query = "
    SELECT products.product_id, products.product_name, products.product_unit, products.product_status
    inventory_order_product.quantity
    FROM products INNER JOIN inventory_order_product
    ON products.product_id = inventory_order_product.product_id
    WHERE products.product_status = 'active' 
    ORDER BY products.product_name ASC
    ";
    $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
    $statement->execute();
    $result = $statement->fetchAll();
    $output = '';
    foreach($result as $row)
    {
        $output .= '<option value="'.$row["product_id"].'">'.$row["product_name"].' ('.$row["quantity"].' '.$row["product_unit"].')</option>';
    }
    return $output;
}
```

I need to select all products that are `active`, that's the reason i also need to select `product_status`

**EDIT: I included the section where i called the function `fill_product_list` and the original function before i tweaked the SQL Statement**

This is where i called the function, at the point of inserting data - creating a new order

```php
if(isset($_POST['btn_action']))
{
    if($_POST['btn_action'] == 'Add')
    {   
        $query = "
        INSERT INTO inventory_order (user_id, inventory_order_total, inventory_order_date, inventory_order_name, inventory_order_address, payment_status, inventory_order_status, inventory_order_created_date) 
        VALUES (:user_id, :inventory_order_total, :inventory_order_date, :inventory_order_name, :inventory_order_address, :payment_status, :inventory_order_status, :inventory_order_created_date)
        ";
        $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
        $statement->execute(
            array(
                ':user_id'                      =>  $_SESSION["userid"],
                ':inventory_order_total'        =>  0,
                ':inventory_order_date'         =>  $_POST['inventory_order_date'],
                ':inventory_order_name'         =>  $_POST['inventory_order_name'],
                ':inventory_order_address'      =>  $_POST['inventory_order_address'],
                ':payment_status'               =>  $_POST['payment_status'],
                ':inventory_order_status'       =>  'active',
                ':inventory_order_created_date' =>  date("Y-m-d")
            )
        );
        $result = $statement->fetchAll();
        $statement = $connect->query("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()");
        $inventory_order_id = $statement->fetchColumn();

        if(isset($inventory_order_id))
        {
            $total_amount = 0;
            for($count = 0; $count<count($_POST["product_id"]); $count++)
            {
                $product_details = fetch_product_details($_POST["product_id"][$count], $connect);
                $sub_query = "
                INSERT INTO inventory_order_product (inventory_order_id, product_id, quantity, price, tax) VALUES (:inventory_order_id, :product_id, :quantity, :price, :tax)
                ";
                $statement = $connect->prepare($sub_query);
                $statement->execute(
                    array(
                        ':inventory_order_id'   =>  $inventory_order_id,
                        ':product_id'           =>  $_POST["product_id"][$count],
                        ':quantity'             =>  $_POST["quantity"][$count],
                        ':price'                =>  $product_details['price'],
                        ':tax'                  =>  $product_details['tax']
                    )
                );
                $base_price = $product_details['price'] * $_POST["quantity"][$count];
                $tax = ($base_price/100)*$product_details['tax'];
                $total_amount = $total_amount + ($base_price + $tax);
            }
            $update_query = "
            UPDATE inventory_order 
            SET inventory_order_total = '".$total_amount."' 
            WHERE inventory_order_id = '".$inventory_order_id."'
            ";
            $statement = $connect->prepare($update_query);
            $statement->execute();
            $result = $statement->fetchAll();
            if(isset($result))
            {
                echo 'Order Created Successfully.';
                echo '<br />';
                echo "Total Price: $". $total_amount;
                echo '<br />';
                echo "Order Number: ".$inventory_order_id;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also, the function was working perfectly before i decided to tweak the SQL statement so that it could capture `Product Name (Quantity ProductUnit)`. Below is the function before i decided to tweak the SQL statement.

```php
function fill_product_list($connect)
{
    $query = "
    SELECT * FROM products 
    WHERE product_status = 'active' 
    ORDER BY product_name ASC
    ";
    $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
    $statement->execute();
    $result = $statement->fetchAll();
    $output = '';
    foreach($result as $row)
    {
        $output .= '<option value="'.$row["product_id"].'">'.$row["product_name"].'</option>';  }
        
    return $output;
}
```

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: Sorry for obvious questions. Did you call this function? If so, how? You only show its definition. Please include fuller code for us to see context. And did you run the SQL outside PHP to ensure it does return data?

Comment: Yes @Parfait i called the function so i could list all `active` products when creating a new order. Also the function was perfectly working before i tried to tweak it to capture `quantity` and `product_unit`. I have included both codes

Comment: When adding an `INNER JOIN` to a query that returns no results means there are no matches between the two tables under the `WHERE` condition. Does `LEFT JOIN` return results? Also, I do not see where second code block calls `fill_product_list`. Finally, it is interesting you parameterize all queries except for the last `UPDATE`. Stay consistent. And why single quotes around numeric values? You might be using MySQL/MariaDB (please tag BTW) that allows this but other DBs would err on type mismatch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by selecting all records.

```php
function fill_product_list($connect)
{
    $query = "
    SELECT *
    FROM products INNER JOIN inventory_order_product
    ON products.product_id = inventory_order_product.product_id
    WHERE products.product_status = 'active' 
    ORDER BY products.product_name ASC
    ";
    $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
    $statement->execute();
    $result = $statement->fetchAll();
    $output = '';
    foreach($result as $row)
    {
        $output .= '<option value="'.$row["product_id"].'">'.$row["product_name"].' ('.$row["quantity"].' '.$row["product_unit"].')</option>';
    }
    return $output;
}
```